# PyQt: Parameterize Connect Function

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a set of 3 list widgets all with drag and drop capabilities.  I am looking to eliminate repeated code and am looking for some help. As you can see in my Dialog class I create 3 Image classes that are drag and drog lists.  As of right now each List Widget corresponds to a connect function.

`self.connect(self.one, SIGNAL("dropped"), self.oneDropped)`

It seems to me that the function `def oneDropped()`could be turned into a function where `self.oneDropped` is an argument, but I am having trouble setting that up and could use some help. Here is my code.

I have only been working with Python for a few weeks so apologies if this is a simple question.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import uic
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

class Image(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(Image, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(72, 72))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.emit(SIGNAL("dropped"), links)
        else:
            event.ignore()

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = uic.loadUi('./qt/default.ui', self)

        self.one = Image(self)
        self.two = Image(self)
        self.three = Image(self)
        self.connect(self.one, SIGNAL("dropped"), self.oneDropped)
        self.connect(self.two, SIGNAL("dropped"), self.twoDropped)
        self.connect(self.three, SIGNAL("dropped"), self.threeDropped)
        self.baseimage_layout.addWidget(self.one)
        self.redimage_layout.addWidget(self.two)
        self.greenimage_layout.addWidget(self.three)


    def oneDropped(self, l):
        for url in l:
            if os.path.exists(url):
                print(url)
                icon = QIcon(url)
                pixmap = icon.pixmap(72, 72)
                icon = QIcon(pixmap)
                item = QListWidgetItem(url, self.one)
                item.setIcon(icon) 

    def twoDropped(self, l):
        for url in l:
            if os.path.exists(url):
                print(url)
                icon = QIcon(url)
                pixmap = icon.pixmap(72, 72)
                icon = QIcon(pixmap)
                item = QListWidgetItem(url, self.two)
                item.setIcon(icon) 

    def threeDropped(self, l):
        for url in l:
            if os.path.exists(url):
                print(url)
                icon = QIcon(url)
                pixmap = icon.pixmap(72, 72)
                icon = QIcon(pixmap)
                item = QListWidgetItem(url, self.three)
                item.setIcon(icon) 

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Dialog()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are using old-style signals and slots, which are outdated and have been removed in more recent versions of PyQt. You should use the [new-style mechanism](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) if possible.

Your example would become:

```
self.one.dropped.connect(self.oneDropped)
```

---

To answer your question, in python you can use a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) to add additional arguments when a slot is called.

First you would define a generic handler that takes an `Image` instance as an argument.

```
def imgDropped(self, l, img):
    for url in l:
        if os.path.exists(url):
            print(url)
            icon = QIcon(url)
            pixmap = icon.pixmap(72, 72)
            icon = QIcon(pixmap)
            item = QListWidgetItem(url, img)
            item.setIcon(icon)
```

Then the signals are connected like this

```
self.one.dropped.connect(lambda l: self.imgDropped(l, self.one))
self.two.dropped.connect(lambda l: self.imgDropped(l, self.two))
self.three.dropped.connect(lambda l: self.imgDropped(l, self.three))
```

If you are unfamiliar with lambdas, they can be a powerful tool when used like this, but beware of potential unintended behaviour due to [late binding](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) of variables.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer as it seemed to work well with my current setup. That being said, your answer appears to be more modern. I am still reading up on how to implement the new-style. 

Is your response with the lambda a separate solution to the new-style mechanism or is that intended to work with my outdated code?

Again apologies if this is a simple question.

Comment: It should work with the old mechanism too. Just replace the `self.oneDropped` etc reference with the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the dropped function and its signal in your image class so you do not have to repeat this function for each class, here is an example :

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import uic
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 

class Image(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(Image, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(72, 72))
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL("dropped"), self.onDropped)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.emit(SIGNAL("dropped"), links)
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def onDropped(self, l):
        for url in l:
            if os.path.exists(url):
                print(url)
                icon = QIcon(url)
                pixmap = icon.pixmap(72, 72)
                icon = QIcon(pixmap)
                item = QListWidgetItem(url, self)
                item.setIcon(icon) 

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = uic.loadUi('./qt/default.ui', self)

        self.one = Image(self)
        self.two = Image(self)
        self.three = Image(self)
        self.baseimage_layout.addWidget(self.one)
        self.redimage_layout.addWidget(self.two)
        self.greenimage_layout.addWidget(self.three)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Dialog()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Moving everything into the `Image` class is good, but then what's the point of the signal? You might as well move the `onDropped` code into `dropEvent` and refactor it as a single loop.

Comment: I agree with you, I tried to stay close from the implementation, maybe he will need this specific signal to be emitted from somewhere else.